# MLR3 : Extract predictions on my train set

Tags: r, prediction, training-data, mlr3

After building my at algorithm, I trained him on my train set and tried to make predictions on the test set. Unfortunately, it's very difficult for me to extract the predictions my model made on my train set...

Here is the code I wrote to extract the predictions of the test set, but no idea for the train...

```
#Auto tuning xgboost
learner_xgboost = lrn("classif.xgboost", predict_type = "prob", nrounds = to_tune(1, 5000), eta = to_tune(1e-4, 1, logscale = TRUE), subsample = to_tune(0.1,1), max_depth = to_tune(1,15), min_child_weight = to_tune(0, 7), colsample_bytree = to_tune(0,1), colsample_bylevel = to_tune(0,1), lambda = to_tune(1e-3, 1e3, logscale = TRUE), alpha = to_tune(1e-3, 1e3, logscale = TRUE))

at_xgboost = auto_tuner(
  tuner= tnr("random_search"),
  learner = learner_xgboost,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  term_evals = 50,
  store_tuning_instance = TRUE,
  store_models = TRUE,
  store_benchmark_result = TRUE
)

set.seed(12345)
at_xgboost$train(task_IG, row_ids = train_rows_outer)
predictions_IG <-at_xgboost$predict(task_IG, row_ids = test_rows)
predictions_IG$score(msr("classif.auc"))
#classif.auc 0.6541043 
predictions_IG$score(msr("classif.bacc"))
#classif.bacc 0.6184822 

row_ids <- predictions_IG$row_ids
  truth <- predictions_IG$truth
  response <- predictions_IG$response
  prob.0 <- predictions_IG$prob[, 1]
  prob.1 <- predictions_IG$prob[, 2]

Predictions_information_gain <- data.table(row_ids = row_ids, truth = truth, response = response, prob.0 = prob.0, prob.1 = prob.1)
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you want to do. 
But why can't you simply set the `row_ids` to the train rows when doing prediction?
The https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/ might also help you.

Comment: When I benchmark or when I use rr, I can extract via the archives the results obtained on my train set with the best metric...but I don't know how to do it with train/predict